# is there a way to get the SPL Transfer Transactions using the solana web3js?

Tags: web3.js, transactions, transfer, getsignaturesforaddress

I want to get the SPL Transfer Transactions just like in the solscan:
https://solscan.io/account/DhRdUKhA3MdB85M4599VhAfSnfwc4ApNiRMCD2iT6i2w#splTransfers

I am using the getSignaturesForAddress but I cannot get the transactions where the wallet address receives the spl token. I can only get the transactions where the wallet sends the spl token to another address.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is to filter out transactions that have been sent to the `Token Program` (which has the pubkey `TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA`) and that are either type `Transfer` or `TransferChecked`.

The following code checks those things.

```
const SPL_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID = "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA";
const TRANSFER_IX_TYPES = ["transferchecked", "transfer"];

...your code to get the transactions you want to check...
    
// `mySignature` contains the current single transaction you want to check 
const confirmedTransaction = await connection.getParsedTransaction(mySignature);

for (let ix of confirmedTransaction.transaction.message.instructions) {
    if(ix.programId == SPL_TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID &&
       TRANSFER_IX_TYPES.includes(ix.parsed.type.toLowerCase())) {
        console.log("instruction data:", JSON.stringify(ix, null, 1));
    }
}
```

Above code will output something like:

```
instruction data: {
 "parsed": {
  "info": {
   "authority": "DhRdUKhA3MdB85M4599VhAfSnfwc4ApNiRMCD2iT6i2w",
   "destination": "3dvMxzKvJsKCewhkkRpRLQKHBQU28Mt9ShDzsKP5wUvg",
   "mint": "EKWrjwb2emCJpzS3Wnqj4x5sD6iV4Sqh6DJ6BdCrSDdm",
   "source": "HDNBmtCKn457mnCcDRSMJmKurxzVG5o28pD8nWF8dRzE",
   "tokenAmount": {
    "amount": "1000000000",
    "decimals": 9,
    "uiAmount": 1,
    "uiAmountString": "1"
   }
  },
  "type": "transferChecked"
 },
 "program": "spl-token",
 "programId": "TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA"
}
```

If you want to dig into a lot of data this might be easier to achieve using a 3rd party, something like [helius.dev's parsed transaction history](https://docs.helius.xyz/solana-apis/enhanced-transactions-api/parsed-transaction-history)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Im new to solana space, so sorry for the noob questions. how can I get the signatures given I have the wallet adress? I need to get the signatures in the SPL Transfer tab.

    `let transactionList = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(publicKey, {limit: 1}, 'finalized');
    let signaturesList = transactionList.map(transaction => transaction.signature)
    let txDetails = await connection.getParsedTransactions(signaturesList, {
        maxSupportedTransactionVersion: 0,
    })`